# EF Core 7 Linq with a 'Contains" generates an SQL with an extra 'or is not null'

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, nullable, ef-core-7.0

I recently updated EF Core 6 to 7, and now a query has become a lot slower than before without any changes. It looks like EF Core translated the LINQ query to a different SQL query.

Versions:

- .NET: 7
- EF Core: 7.0.3

This is the LINQ query:

**UPDATE**: This is wrong, the list labels did contain a `null`. It wasn't expected at all and because we didn't have the nullable reference types turned on we didn't catch it sooner.

```cs
int userId = 3;
List<string> labels = new () { "one", "two", "three" };
List<RecordEntity> alreadySyncedEvents = await _dbContext.RecordEntities
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .Where(x => labels.Contains(x.Label))
    .Include(x => x.ExtraData)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is the generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Label], [a0].[Id], [a0].[ExtraData]
FROM [RecordEntities] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [ExtraDataEntities] AS [a0] ON [a].[Id] = [a0].[RecordId]
WHERE ([a].[UserId] = 3) AND ([a].[Label] IN (N'one', N'two', N'three') OR ([a].[Label] IS NULL))
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
```

The problem is that the `OR ([a].[Label] IS NULL)` causes this query to return over 13k records while before the switch to EF Core 7 it returned 1. The only thing it added was the extra `OR` condition.

Is this because I don't use nullable reference types and that string is by default nullable?
Nullable reference types are completely disabled in this project.

Comment: That seems like a bug in EF Core 7 to me - in C#, `Contains` will return `False` if `x.Label` is `null`, but that SQL will return `True`.

Comment: Agree with @NetMage, looks like a bug.

Comment: One I can't duplicate, even including the async and an `Include`. Apparently there is more going on.

Comment: Can't reproduce either. There must be something else in your model/configuration not shown here. Please provide [mre].

Comment: Are you sure that actual list does not contain nulls?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra condition

```cs
.Where(x => labels != null && labels.Contains(x.Label))
```

It does seem to be a bug, although you may want to check the configuration for `UseRelationalNulls(true)`, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons#using-relational-null-semantics

Answer (score 0):

Since they changed the behaviour of `OR` operator in EF Core 7, you need to explicitly check for null values.

Add the following check with `||` operator to your second `Where()` like :

```
.Where(x => labels.Contains(x.Label) || x.Label == null)
```

It should behave as old EF would.

Comment: Is this backwards? The OP wants the SQL test against `NULL` removed, not added...

Comment: @NetMage We encountered the similar case. It is weird that the translation of `OR` caused performance issues, but nullable strings are one of the reason I think.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The list `labels` isn't expected to contain null, because it's based on a list we get from another API (Microsoft Graph API) where we shouldn't expect a null value. But because of a bug, a null value did slip in there. So EF Core added a `OR ([a].[Label] IS NULL)`. If I explicitly filter the nulls out of the list the query no longer contains the `OR ([a].[Label] IS NULL)`.

It's a good thing that we are starting to enable nullable reference types in another branch, that way we would've spotted it sooner.

It's still a weird coincidence that this happens exactly the day that we switch to EF Core 7. I'll keep investigating.